# PsExec: Handle is invalid | Error deriving session key

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, psexec

While running some automated scripts I get the following error:

```
Handle is invalid.
Connecting to local system...
Starting PSEXESVC service on local system...
Connecting with PsExec service on XXX...
Error deriving session key
```

I am running a script on one VM (Ubuntu 14), this script launches a script on another VM (Windows 7) Using winexe.

The script launched on the Windows 7 VM used to work, but recently I am getting the above error. There is no active session on the Windows 7 VM, and the VM is always reverted to a previous snapshot before this script is run. So I know that nothing has changed on the Windows 7 VM.

The only thing that could possibly have changed is the order in which I do some operations, but I have been unable to reproduce the problem when testing manually. I used to run operations one at a time, but recently have begun multiprocessing/threading my operations simultaneously to save time. **This may be the problem**, ***but it shouldn't be***.

Is there any way for me to reproduce the problem? Or retrieve better logs? Or better yet - solve the problem with some special flags or settings?

The command that is run on the windows machine is as follows:

```
psexec -accepteula -e -h -u Administrator -p PASSWORD -i 0 PATH_TO_FILE
```

The command that is run from the linux machine to initiate the script on the Windows machine is:

```
winexe -U DOMAIN\\Administrator%PASSWORD //X.X.X.X SCRIPT
```

**Notes:**

- Trying to run the psexec command without the -i does not work either.
- Running the script manually from the Linux machine works
  successfully.
- Running the script manually from the Windows machine
  works successfully.
- I am fairly certain the problem is with the psexec, though I am open to other solutions.

Comment: What happens if you restart the Server service? You could be running out of sessions. Also try removing the `-e`, since that causes the profile to not be loaded.

Comment: Hi @Inbar, any luck with this ? I have the exact same problem with PsExec.

Comment: @BilalHalayqa this was a number of years ago. I don't recall exactly how I resolved it. But I could find the code somewhere. I think that what I ended up doing was having a script on windows run the command again, IE. The running a new command on windows instead of having it be the result of the command run by winexe. So it would be winexe trigger a script on the windows, which trigger a new process which runs psexec. But I'll look for the solution

Comment: Actually, I am using PsExec to start the process on a remote server. It works if I run it through windows CMD, it works locally, works remotely works everywhere except if I run the command inside an ASP.net page under IIS, I get the error you are getting here. Some say its an IIS security restriction, but I am searching how to overcome that as the IIS is for internal usage. I am pretty sure about the permissions though ...